# Selenium Xpath WebElement Text not printing

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to extract text using the following code. I do not get any error message. And nothing is returned when I print the output variable.

```
helpful_vote = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@data-hook="helpful-vote-statement"]')
vote_text = helpful_vote.text
print( vote_text )
```

When I look at the log (picture below), the text I am trying to retrieve is shown under a sub element called *"parent"*. Is there another xpath function or a Python method I should use to extract the text?

[image]

Comment: *" I do not get any error message"* I'm quite sure that you should get an exception with your code as you're trying to get `text` property of *list* which doesn't have such property. Update your code properly. Case also matters in Python and `Print` doesn't mean the same as `print`

Answer (score 0):

You use method `find_elements_by_xpath`, which returns list of elements. So you don't have property `text` in `list` object. You can select the first(or any other you need) element of the `helpful_vote` and access its `text` property, or iterate the list and get `text` from each XPath result.

But if you expect to have single result from that XPath, just use method `find_element_by_xpath` which returns the single element.
So your code will be like this:

```
helpful_vote = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-hook="helpful-vote-statement"]')
vote_text = helpful_vote.text
print(vote_text)
```

You can find more info at [Selenium docs for Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

***UPDATE:*** I don't clearly understand what you want to achieve. If you want to iterate XPath result and print `text` of each element, then this code works for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver.exe')
link = 'https://www.amazon.com/Gerber-Organic-Foods-Veggie-Variety/product-reviews/B00D05BPTW/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews'
browser.get(link)
time.sleep(6)
helpful_vote = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@data-hook="helpful-vote-statement"]')

for attr1 in helpful_vote:
    Votes = attr1.text
    print(Votes)

browser.close()
```

The output is:

*7 people found this helpful*
*3 people found this helpful*
*20 people found this helpful*
*3 people found this helpful*
*One person found this helpful*
*5 people found this helpful*
*6 people found this helpful*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that **find_elements_by_xpath** returns a list of elements. I know which element of the list contains the relevant text, its name is "parent". I am a Python beginner. I tried helpful_vote['parent'].text but it did not work (nothing printed, no error message).

Comment: In Python class `list` has no attribute `parent`. And you can't index array with strings. On attached screenshot you clearly can see  expanded **6th** element of an array, and that element has attribute `parent`. So you can access it by `helpful_vote[6].parent`.

Comment: I tried the suggestion **helpful_vote[6].parent** but I still face the same issue (nothing printed, no error message)

Comment: Below the code. Thanks for your help. `chromedriver_path = r'C:\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path, options=options)  
                     link = 'https://www.amazon.com/Gerber-Organic-Foods-Veggie-Variety/product-reviews/B00D05BPTW/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews'
browser.get(link)
time.sleep(6)
helpful_vote = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@data-hook="helpful-vote-statement"]')
for attr1 in zip(helpful_vote):  
    Votes = attr2[6].parent.text  
    print(Votes)`

Comment: Sorry for the format of the code in my previous comment. I cannot find a way to break lines. Thanks

Comment: You can update your question with that piece of code. In comments you can't use multiple lines. Also, I've updated the answer with code that works for me.

Comment: Thanks Mike - What I submitted is a simplified code because of the number of character limit in Comments. In reality, I am extracting 6 variables and I am using a zip function in itertools Python module. See below. Could that be my problem since 1 variable work for you. **for attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4, attr5, attr6 in zip (Profile_name, review_title, review_date, review_content, rating, helpful_vote):**

Comment: When I loop without the zip function, I get the error message: **ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 6)**

Comment: So just update(edit) your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53349835/7128891) with that full code.

Comment: I used **zip_longest** instead of **zip** and output is showing. Now I am getting another error only for records: 
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'**

Comment: The error **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'** is caused by one variable which is sometimes not populated (no votes provided). I am finding out a way to print NO DATA when this happen and avoid the error. Thanks

Comment: ANY SUGGESTION? I tried the following but I still get the "NoneType" error.         **try:
            R_Votes = attr5.text
   except NoSuchElementException:
            R_Votes =str('NO DATA')**

Comment: I got a workaround. Instead if except **except NoSuchElementException:** , use instead **except AttributeError**

Comment: Since I don't see the updated question with enough code, I can't suggest better way. You definitely need to learn more Python. And remember - don't pollute comment section, better update the original question. Hope you fixed the errors. Good luck!